# Convert pandas DateTimeIndex to Unix Time?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the idiomatic way of converting a pandas DateTimeIndex to (an iterable of) Unix Time? 
This is probably not the way to go:

```
[time.mktime(t.timetuple()) for t in my_data_frame.index.to_pydatetime()]
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As `DatetimeIndex` is `ndarray` under the hood, you can do the conversion without a comprehension (much faster).

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: from datetime import datetime

In [4]: dates = [datetime(2012, 5, 1), datetime(2012, 5, 2), datetime(2012, 5, 3)]
   ...: index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates)
   ...: 
In [5]: index.astype(np.int64)
Out[5]: array([1335830400000000000, 1335916800000000000, 1336003200000000000], 
        dtype=int64)

In [6]: index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
Out[6]: array([1335830400, 1335916800, 1336003200], dtype=int64)

%timeit [t.value // 10 ** 9 for t in index]
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 us per loop

%timeit index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.4 us per loop
```

Comment: I was annoyed I couldn't remember how to access this as an array, of course it's `.as_type(int64)` :)

Comment: @AndyHayden -- well usually it's the other way around :)

Comment: In case it's not clear, `index.astype(np.int64)` returns the time in nanoseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve NaT or NaN with this method? Else you get a large negative value.

Answer (score 47):

Note: Timestamp is just unix time with nanoseconds (so divide it by 10**9):

```py
[t.value // 10 ** 9 for t in tsframe.index]
```

For example:

```
In [1]: t = pd.Timestamp('2000-02-11 00:00:00')

In [2]: t
Out[2]: <Timestamp: 2000-02-11 00:00:00>

In [3]: t.value
Out[3]: 950227200000000000L

In [4]: time.mktime(t.timetuple())
Out[4]: 950227200.0
```

As @root points out it's faster to extract the array of values directly:

```py
tsframe.index.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
```

Comment: this is quite embarrassingly easy… (and I could have sworn I tried t.value, turns out I only tried tsframe.index.value)

Comment: @ChristianGeier It's only easy when you know the answer! It's crazy that `tsframe.index.values` is different... confusing.

Answer (score 13):

A summary of other answers:

```
df['<time_col>'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

If you want to keep the milliseconds divide by `10**6` instead

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the other answers: `//10**9` will do a flooring divide, which gives full past seconds rather than the nearest value in seconds. A simple way to get more reasonable rounding, if that is desired, is to add `5*10**8 - 1` before doing the flooring divide.

Answer (score 2):

To address the case of NaT, which above solutions will convert to large negative ints, in pandas>=0.24 a possible solution would be:

```py
def datetime_to_epoch(ser):
    """Don't convert NaT to large negative values."""
    if ser.hasnans:
        res = ser.dropna().astype('int64').astype('Int64').reindex(index=ser.index)
    else:
        res = ser.astype('int64')

    return res // 10**9
```

In the case of missing values this will return the nullable int type 'Int64' (ExtensionType pd.Int64Dtype):

```
In [5]: dt = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["2019-08-21", "2018-07-28", np.nan]))                                                                                                                                                                                                    
In [6]: datetime_to_epoch(dt)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: 
0    1566345600
1    1532736000
2           NaN
dtype: Int64
```

Otherwise a regular int64:

```
In [7]: datetime_to_epoch(dt[:2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[7]: 
0    1566345600
1    1532736000
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from the other answers

```
dframe['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

prints the following warning as of the time of my post:

> FutureWarning: casting datetime64[ns] values to int64 with
> .astype(...) is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use
> .view(...) instead.

So use the following instead:

```
dframe['datetime'].view(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried this on the datetime column of your dataframe:

```
dframe['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

& that you are struggling with the following error:`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'` you can just use these two lines :

```py
dframe.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dframe['datetime'])
dframe['datetime']= dframe.index.astype(np.int64)// 10**9
```