# Using scikit-learn (sklearn), how to handle missing data for linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I tried this but couldn't get it to work for my data: 
[Use Scikit Learn to do linear regression on a time series pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748717/use-scikit-learn-to-do-linear-regression-on-a-time-series-pandas-data-frame)

My data consists of 2 DataFrames. `DataFrame_1.shape = (40,5000)` and `DataFrame_2.shape = (40,74)`.  I'm trying to do some type of linear regression, but `DataFrame_2` contains `NaN` missing data values.  When I `DataFrame_2.dropna(how="any")` the shape drops to `(2,74)`.

**Is there any linear regression algorithm in sklearn that can handle `NaN` values?**

I'm modeling it after the `load_boston` from `sklearn.datasets` where `X,y = boston.data, boston.target = (506,13),(506,)`

Here's my simplified code:

```
X = DataFrame_1
for col in DataFrame_2.columns:
    y = DataFrame_2[col]
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X,y)

#ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I did the above format to get the shapes to match up of the matrices

If posting the `DataFrame_2` would help, please comment below and I'll add it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fill in the null values in `y` with imputation. In `scikit-learn` this is done with the following code snippet:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer()
y_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(y)
```

Otherwise, you might want to build your model using a subset of the 74 columns as predictors, perhaps some of your columns contain less null values?

Comment: I tried this with my column and got `TypeError: unbound method fit_transform() must be called with Imputer instance as first argument (got Series instance instead)` then tried it with the whole DataFrame and got the same thing (w/ DataFrame instead of Series)

Comment: with scikit you need to call things on the underlying numpy arrays not the dataframes themself; you should have already set `X=DataFrame_1.values` and `y=Dataframe_2.values`

Comment: oops also i gave you the wrong syntax for the imputer, i've fixed the code

Comment: I saw somehwere `imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)` . How would this alter the default?

Comment: those are the defaults, i guess it's just showing you that you can change them if you want

Comment: What I don't understand is why `y_imputed` returns a numpy array that differs in length from the original len of the column in the original data frame?  The non-imputed numbers are included, so its not a matter of showing "imputed only".  What gives?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew the shape of the arrays should definitely be the same, if you're still having this problem, post a question about it and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: Imputer is deprecated in sklearn 0.23.2, use sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer

Answer (score 4):

If your variable is a DataFrame, you could use `fillna`. Here I replaced the missing data with the mean of that column.

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yes! This is the default function of the sklearn imputer