# Performing sklearn.linearmodel ridge regression on xarray data which contains nan elements

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-xarray

I'm attempting to perform a multiple linear regression with ridge corrections to determine the relationship between certain spatial variables in an xarray Dataframe. Because these are observed data, there are occasionally NaN values in the data, which sklearn doesn't natively handle. I've attempted using `data.interpolate_na(fill_value='extrapolate')`, but this fails to replace all the NaN values. A working solution is to use `data.fillna(0)`, but this could be problematic because I would prefer not to 'invent' data from whole cloth when something like interpolating or masking would be better. My code is below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

def detrend_dim(da, dim, deg=1): # removes (temporal) trends from data
    # detrend along a single dimension
    p = da.polyfit(dim=dim, deg=deg)
    fit = xr.polyval(da[dim], p.polyfit_coefficients)
    return da - fit

#loading and preprocessing data
data = xr.open_dataset('reanalysisdata.nc')
data2 = xr.open_dataset('satellitedata.nc')
land = xr.open_dataset('twoptfivedeglandmask.nc')
data2.coords['mask'] = (('lat', 'lon'), land.FRLAND.mean(dim='time').data)
data2 = data2.where(data2.mask == 0)
data.coords['mask'] = (('lat', 'lon'), land.FRLAND.mean(dim='time').data)
data = data.where(data.mask == 0)

#trying to deal with NaN values
data = data.fillna(0)
data2 = data2.fillna(0)

#removing time trends
data['x1'] = detrend_dim(data.x1, 'time')
data['x2'] = detrend_dim(data.x2, 'time')
data['x3'] = detrend_dim(data.x3, 'time')
data2['y'] = detrend_dim(data2.y, 'time')

#removing seasonal cycle
dataM = data.groupby('time.month')
dataU = dataM - dataM.mean()
data2M = data2.groupby('time.month')
data2U = data2M - data2M.mean()

#performing regression
a = np.zeros((72,144,3))
for i in range(len(data.lat)):
    for j in range(len(data.lon)):
        a[i,j,:] = (Ridge().fit(np.array((dataU.isel(lev=2).x1.values[:,i,j].reshape(-1,1),
                    dataU.isel(lev=2).x2.values[:,i,j].reshape(-1,1),
                    dataU.isel(lev=2).x3.values[:,i,j].reshape(-1,1))).reshape(108,3),
                    data2U.y.values[:,i,j].reshape(108)).coef_)
dataU = data.assign_coords(varname=['x1','x2','x3'])
dataU['multiple_reg_coeff'] = (('lat','lon','varname'), a)
```

Do I need to check for NaNs iteratively for each variable? There are regressions in sklearn.linear_model which do natively handle NaNs, but I have less of an understanding of the math which underlies them than I do ridge regression.

Answer (score 0):

sklearn handles the Nan values using imputation as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114098/15791525

Although imputed data are not 'invent', you could still want to avoid new values in your dataset. In that case I suggest you to discard data groups with Nan values if it's possible without losing too many samples.